# LPDDR on separate replaceable modules / boards - possible? drawbacks?

Tags: low-power, sdram, ddr

I've read that [LPDDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LPDDR) is more efficient in active states and times more energy efficient than [DDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM) in inactive states, e.g. in [Performance vs power in off-chip DDR SDRAM](https://www.powersystemsdesign.com/articles/performance-vs-power-in-off-chip-ddr-sdram/22/5893), there is a mentioning of technical differences (**emphasis mine**):

> Low-power DDR SDRAM consumes less power in active mode. For example,
> the low-power variants **forgo the common parallel termination**
> mainstream DDR2 and DDR3 devices use. They also reduce power in
> standby mode by, for example, **forgoing the on-chip DLL** (delay-locked
> loop) that standard DDR memory includes.

I have not seen / read about LPDDR being on separate replaceable modules as opposed to DDR where one can easily replace (thought not hot-swap) 4GB module with 16GB.

I'm not technical expert, I do not fully understand that the above quoted difference means. Can LPDDR modules (and sockets for them on motherboards along with wires to processors/SoC) be manufactured with not much greater effort (if calculated from scratch, taking into account development of the modules design) than DDR? What would be effect on current levels of energy savings of LPDDR vs DDR of such modularity?

For context, the thought probably originated partly due to watching [ifixit: MacBook Pro 2021 Teardown: Easier to Repair, Harder to Score](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLtkukeua_c) (though comment on performance, but AFAIK most are amazed by battery life of MacBook M1, hence my question).

> for now this score includes a penalty for integrated storage and
> memory like any other laptop would but if we learn that this level of
> performance is truly impossible without that we will readjust our
> expectations

Answer (score 1):

LPDDR usually runs at lower voltages than DDR and so will usually use less power per bit transferred (in addition to other architectural differences).  You could probably extend LPDDR onto a longer, socketed bus, but extending the length of the bus is going to make low voltage operation harder. At the same time, the usual point of socketing memory is to allow you to install more of it, which is harder to do with LPDDR since capacities are (usually) lower.

So could you?  Probably.  Would it make sense?  Probably not.  We have a standard for socketed, high capacity DRAM.  We have another a standard designed for on board, lower to moderate capacity DRAM.  Picking the tool made for the job is usually going to work better.

As for your question about laptops, I doubt the memory bus power consumption is a dominating factor in overall power consumption.  It is only a modest fraction of total memory power consumption, and memory power consumption is typically a lot smaller than the CPU and display.

Comment: Thank you. Please clarify some points: "We have a standard for socketed, high capacity DRAM." So there is no standard at all for socketed LPDDR (like how many pins module/socket should have etc), right? for neither of generations LPDDR2,3,4?

Comment: "but extending the length of the bus is going to make low voltage operation harder." But DDR use less and less voltage with each generation and about match LPDDR of previous generation. What extending here means in more layman terms?

Comment: As for the business case (e.g. laptops), passive/idle consumption is important IMO as e.g. one can casually leave LPDDR based laptop on suspend between occasional use for several days but DDR based one would produce significant battery grain in suspend and last much less with same usage behavior.

Comment: @Martian2020 I think you asked me about socketed LPDDR last week. See that answer. To extend means to make something longer.

Comment: Found: "You could probably socket LPDDR, but I have never seen that done." Nothing about standards as far as I've found. Why moving from memory chips soldered on same board with SoC to socketed one would require extending the length of the bus? (I assume you meant bus from SoC, right?)

Comment: @Martian2020 A socket is a physical device with a thickness and width. The bus will become longer because of this added length and the additional length required to get traces into and out of the socket.

Comment: thank you. I just had incorrect mental picture of the bus, mistaking width with length, now it is clear. Now however I would argue that as number of chips grow to allow more ram (64GB of LPDDR in new Macbooks now already), several sockets may allow "3D stacking" and even reduce the length.